# Postgres column with string unicode values

Tags: json, regex, postgresql, unicode

i have a column `query_params` with type TEXT but the values are stored as a string unicode. each value in the column is prefixed with a `u` and i'm struggling to remove it

Is there a way to remove the `u` from the values and convert the values dictionary to columns?

for example, the query `SELECT query_params FROM api_log LIMIT 2` returns two rows

```
{
  u'state': u'CA',
  u'page_size': u'1000',
  u'market': u'Western',
  u'requested_at': u'2014-10-28T00:00:00+00:00'
},
{
  u'state': u'NY',
  u'page_size': u'1000',
  u'market': u'Eastern',
  u'requested_at': u'2014-10-28T00:10:00+00:00'
}
```

is it possible to handle unicode in postgres and convert to columns:

```
state | page_size | market   | requested_at
------+-----------+----------+---------------------------
CA    | 1000      | Western  | 2014-10-28T00:00:00+00:00
NY    | 1000      | Eastern  | 2014-10-28T00:10:00+00:00
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the example text a single row or two rows?

Comment: @klin the example is in a single row. i'll update the description for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `u` letters and replace single quotes with double ones to get properly formatted json. Then you can use the `->>` operator to get its attributes:

```
select 
    v->>'state' as state,
    v->>'page_size' as page_size,
    v->>'market' as market,
    v->>'requested_at' as requested_at
from (
    select regexp_replace(query_params, 'u\''([^\'']*)\''', '"\1"', 'g')::json as v
    from api_log
    ) s;
```

Test the solution in [SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2dc5a/18)

Read about POSIX Regular Expression in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Find an explanation of the regexp expression in [regex101.com.](https://regex101.com/r/jQj7OY/2)

Comment: thanks so much..the SqlFiddle seems to work but when i tried your solution in it returns an error: `[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Token "u" is invalid.`
Also, if you can explain whats happening in the first part of the `regexp_replace` function that would be a huge help.

Comment: This means that the example text is not exactly the same as the actual one. See the updated answer.

Comment: Hey. thanks so much. the additional information on regexp was super helpful to learn explanation of the expression.